# Correlated signal from two sensors in one circuit

Tags: sensors

I have water level/humidity sensor and a LDR diode hooked to arduino like this (the resistor is 10k)
[image: schema]

- On `A0` I can read signal from water sensor (blue)
- On `A1` I can read signal from light sensor (yellow)

The problem is that both signals seem to be correlated. When I dip the water sensor to water and keep the light levels the same, the signal from light goes up as well (dramatically).

I suspect that this is due to Ohm's law. The voltage in a circuit depends on the total resistance of the circuit. Both sensors act as a sort of resistors so when one's resistance changes the voltage in the circuit changes as well.

How can I wire the sensors such that the change in resistance of either sensor doesn't affect the second? Or do I need a separate power supply for each sensor?

Comment: is the light sensor wiring right? shouldn't the resistor connect to ground?

Comment: I get some signal, so I guess it is (row 37)

Comment: You can try to read another channel between them - connected to ground to discharge sampling capacitor.

Comment: @KIIV I am not sure if I follow (still learning the lingo). You mean like connecting a simple resistor to GND and `A3` (same as the LDR is wired). and read `A0` (water) -> `A3` (discharge)  --> `A1` (light)?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. But you can short A3 to the ground directly. And sequence would be:  A3 (discharge), A0 (water), A3 (discharge), A1 (light). Now it shouldn't be crosstalking between A0 and A1 as it starts the measure on completely discharged capacitor. Now it'll depend on output impedance of sensors only.

Comment: > short A3 to the ground directly You mean a jumper from row 45 GND to A3 directly? just making sure

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213851/arduino-analogread-neighbor-pin-noise-on-adc-even-with-big-delay

Comment: I still think the problem is the pullup resistor

Comment: I've unplugged the whole thing and rebuilt from scratch. That didn't work initally, so I wired A3 to GND directly and read a value from that. Then I unplugged the `A3-GND` and it seems to be working just fine even without it. Thanks to both of you! @Juraj, if you compile the A3-GND tip to an answer I will happily accept it, since that seemed to help imo

Comment: @KIIV knew what to do, answer is his

Comment: of course (sorry @KIIV !) just swapped the two names. Thanks to both of you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've found the same humidity sensor, it has pretty big output impedance and the maximum input impedance for the `ADC` input is `10kOhms`. According the the datasheet the recommended minimum load for the sensor is about `80kOhms` (?). That means readings of humidity sensor will be highly affected by sampling capacitor initial charge (= the value of previous reading).

Basically reading `GND` between sensor readings helps to separate the results from each other, but the humidity sensor won't be able to charge sampling capacitor to its output voltage without amplifying the current (you'll get values much lower than it should be).

Or you can repeat the readings on humidity sensor channel several times until the value is more "stable".